# Inserting into data structure in O(1) time while maintaining index order

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

Is there a data structure with elements that can be indexed whose insertion runtime is O(1)? So for example, I could index the data structure like so: `a[4]`, and yet when inserting an element at an arbitrary place in the data structure that the runtime is O(1)? Note that the data structure does not maintain sorted order, just the ability for each sequential element to have an index.

I don't think its possible, since inserting somewhere that is not at the end or beginning of the ordered data structure would mean that all the indicies after insertion must be updated to know that their index has increased by 1, which would take worst case O(n) time. If the answer is no, could someone prove it mathematically?

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I want to maintain the order of insertion of elements, so upon inserting, the item inserted remains sequentially between the two elements it was placed between.

Comment: A hash table can do this, an integer index is simply a very limited form of a key.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I'll tell you why a hashtable can't do this, because if I want to insert an element in between two others, I need to increment all the indexes of all the keys that come after it. So no, nice try, a hashtable doesn't work here

Comment: I think it's not clear if you're talking about arranging elements by index, or mapping elements to indices, or both.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I want a data structure that can arrange elements by index and also have O(1) insertion time. The problem is, it seems that by doing this, every element after the insertion point would need to have its index changed. So there has to be some way to automatically change all their indexes or some way to calculate the index on the fly based on some stored information. I'm just not sure its possible

Comment: Inserting by index, or can you insert by reference to an adjacent element?

Comment: The best way to clarify the question would be to provide a complete prototype of this hypothetical data structure. i.e., a description and signature for every method / operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are looking to solve is called the [list labeling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List-labeling_problem).

There are lower bounds on the cost that depend on the relationship between the the maximum number of labels you need (n), and the number of possible labels (m).

If n is in O(log m), i.e., if the number of possible labels is exponential in the number of labels you need at any one time, then O(1) cost per operation is achievable... but this is not the usual case.

If n is in O(m), i.e., if they are proportional, then O(log<sup>2</sup> n) per operation is the best you can do, and the algorithm is complicated.

If n <= m<sup>2</sup>, then you can do O(log N).  Amortized O(log N) is simple, and O(log N) worst case is hard.  Both algorithms are described in [this paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esleator/papers/maintaining-order.pdf) by Dietz and Sleator.  The hard way makes use of the O(log<sup>2</sup> n) algorithm mentioned above.

HOWEVER, maybe you don't really need labels.  If you just need to be able to compare the order of two items in the collection, then you are solving a slightly different problem called "[list order maintenance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-maintenance_problem)".  This problem *can* actually be solved in constant time -- O(1) cost per operation and O(1) cost to compare the order of two items -- although again O(1) amortized cost is a lot easier to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting into slot `i`, append the element which was first at slot `i` to the end of the sequence.

If the sequence capacity must be grown, then this growing may not necessarily be O(1).

Comment: This is a nice idea, thanks for your input. The thing is it doesn't maintain the inherent order that the user of the data structure would like to assume. I want all elements to remain in their places

Comment: @JakeKorman In the question it says "**Note that the data structure does not maintain sorted order, just the ability for each sequential element to have an index.**" I thought this meant that the relative order doesn't matter. Am I misinterpreting?

Comment: I hear what you are saying, my words did imply that, I will edit the question